# is setting inline css style cpu expensive?

Tags: javascript, css, cpu-usage

How cpu intensive is to set a inline css style?

I am having a ticker, which updates css of the element 50 times a second:

```
//update 50 times each second
if(sthTrue){
  elementRef.style.display = "none";
}else{
  elementRef.style.display = "";
}
```

if `display` is already `none`, than on the next iteration it will also be set to `none`. Is it better to wrap it in additional if block?

```
lastDisplayStyle = "";
//update 50 times each second
if(sthTrue){
 if(lastDisplayStyle==""){
   elementRef.style.display = "none";
   lastDisplayStyle = "none";
  }
}else{
 if(lastDisplayStyle=="none"){
   elementRef.style.display = "";
   lastDisplayStyle = "";
   }
}
```

This omits setting css on every iteration, but on expense of additional `if` check. Which is more cpu cycles friendly?

Comment: run a bechmark and see

Comment: It looks like you have the "ticker" updating according to some other value. Why not have the code that is responsible for changing that other value trigger the "update ticker" code?

Comment: In general, anything that modifies the DOM is likely to be more expensive than ordinary JS variables, since it triggers rendering the display. But the browser might be smart about assigning the same value to an attribute.

Comment: Yes, it's going to be expensive. I'd suggest to detect the even that makes "sthTrue" change, and then update the dom acordingly instead of using a ticker to check it's state 50 times every second.